# How to efficiently change the field in binary linked list?

Tags: matlab

I have a piece of Matlab code that is essentially a binary linked list:

```
Node{1}=My_Model;
Node{2}=Node{1}.branch_link{1};
Node{3}=Node{1}.branch_link{2};
Node{4}=Node{2}.branch_link{1};
Node{5}=Node{2}.branch_link{2};
Node{6}=Node{3}.branch_link{1};
Node{7}=Node{3}.branch_link{2};
Node{8}=Node{4}.branch_link{1};
Node{9}=Node{4}.branch_link{2};
...
Node{22}=Node{14}.branch_link{1};
```

All nodes here are "struct" type and have a field called "feature" among other fields. I want to replace every node's "feature" with a "featureNew". But it's very inefficient to manually do it like

```
My_Model.branch_link{2}.branch_link{2}.branch_link{1}.branch_link{1}.feature=featureNew{22};
```

Is there an easier way (maybe use pointer or reference, but I don't know it in Matlab)? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to [traverses the whole tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal), which is easiest done with a recursive function. Untested example:

```
function tree_set_struct(node, field, value)
% traverses tree in depth-first, pre-order way and sets node.field to value.
% Children are in node.branch_link, which should be an empty cell array
% for leaf nodes.

% first update current node
node.(field) = value;

% then recursively call function on all children. 
for ichild=1:length(node.branch_link)
    child = node.branch_link{ichild};
    tree_set_struct(child, field, value);
end
```

Usage should be

```
tree_set_struct(My_Model, 'feature', featureNew)
```